# WCF, Unity Container Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, dependency-injection, enterprise-library

I am working on WCF with Unity Dependency injection. Everything was working fine in VS2012 Service is in 32 bit version. Now We are upgrading service to x64 bit version, Service getting update success. But while running the application i am getting Unity Exception, the web.config file also ok.

Exception is :

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type name or alias ReportDecodingDefault could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

Web.Config :

```
  <typeAlias alias="ISignatureCalculation" type="Diagnostics.Report.Repository.Contract.ISignatureCalculation, Diagnostics.Report.Repository.Contract" />
  <typeAlias alias="SignatureCalculationDefault" type="Diagnostics.Report.Signature.SignatureCalculation, Diagnostics.Report.Signature" />
  <typeAlias alias="SignatureCalculationBGL" type="Diagnostics.Report.Signature.BGL.SignatureCalculation, Diagnostics.Report.Signature.BGL" />
  <typeAlias alias="SignatureCalculationPrototyp" type="ErrorReportAnalyzer.SignatureCalculator, ErrorReportAnalyzer" />
  <typeAlias alias="SignatureCalculationRefactored" type="ExceptionBasedAndReferencesMappingAlgorithm.SignatureCalculator, ExceptionBasedAndReferencesMappingAlgorithm" />

  <typeAlias alias="IDataStore" type="Diagnostics.Report.Repository.Contract.IDataStore, Diagnostics.Report.Repository.Contract" />
  <typeAlias alias="DataStoreDefault" type="Diagnostics.Report.Repository.SqlDb.SqlDataManager, Diagnostics.Report.Repository.SqlDb" />
</typeAliases>
  <container>
  <types>
     <type type="IReportDecoding" mapTo="ReportDecodingDefault"></type>
    <type type="ISignatureCalculation" mapTo="SignatureCalculationRefactored"></type>
    <type type="IDataStore" mapTo="DataStoreDefault"></type>
  </types>
    </container>
</unity>
```

Getting exception while loading Configuration

Container = newUnityContainer();

Container.LoadConfiguration();  (Here exception)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

LoadConfiguration will use the configuration file where ReportDecodingDefault is defined. Maybe this class is implemented in a library that is still compiled as 32 bit?

Comment: HI Jeroen, Thanks for reply. "ReportDecodingDefault " class library was compiled in x64 only not in 32 bit. any other clues please

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051347/xml-config-changes-in-unity-2-0). Are you sure that there is no Unity upgrade executed? I also noticed that in the initial question there is no typealias for ReportDecodingDefault.